# Selecting part of text inside paragraph CSS

Tags: html, css

Is possible to select part of text in CSS3 until "br" badge whitout editing html.
I want to select this part:

> "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text <br/> 
of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

Comment: You want to select it? What do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `first-line` modifier as shown below:

```
p:first-line { 
   color: red;
}
```

As @JordanS has correctly highlighted, there are cases where this will fail. For a robust solution you either update the HTML or use javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/01c5tbst/

**Update:**

For posterity the solution actually desired to apply the style only to the first line of the first matching element on the page, so the final solution actually was this:

```
p:first-of-type::first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is working, but is possible to select only first (first-line)? I mean first paragraph, first line only. Not all paragraphs first line.

Comment: You're spot on @JordanS. In reality there is no reliable means of doing this with a CSS only solution.

Comment: Yeah. You will need to restructure your HTML or get crafty with JS.

Comment: If this is the first paragraph, simply `p:first-child::first-line` will do.

Comment: See the jsfiddle in my comment, I am using the example provided by MrLister.

Comment: Try this instead: `p:first-of-type::first-line`